multiplication of non-commutative exponent
my result is diffrent from the equation (24) of DOI:10.1063/1.1664490 of a minus.
In short words: When using BCH formula the element A is "-b'H" which leads to the sin/sinh(-b'H). And this is diffrent from the orginal article which has no minus.[enter image description here][1]
By using bch formula:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:bch1}
e^{A}Be^{-A}=B+[A,B]+\frac{1}{2}[A,[A,B]]+\ldots+\frac{1}{n!}\underbrace{[A,\ldots[A,B]..]}_{\textrm{n's}}+\ldots
\end{equation}
It becomes:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:bch2}
e^{-H}Be^{H}=B+[-H,B]+\frac{1}{2}[-H,[-H,B]]+\ldots+\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\underbrace{[A,\ldots[A,B]..]}_{\textrm{n's}}+\ldots
\end{equation}
the parameter is $\tau$：$[H,P]=\pm \frac{1}{\tau^2}K$
Next if you are curious about where the sin/cos comes. it comes from the commutator, the commutator change the operator so we need to separated by power:
\begin{align} \label{eq:kine2}
&e^{bH} e^{a\cdot P} e^{a\cdot P } e^{-i\theta n\cdot J}e^{b'H} e^{n\cdot J} e^{v'\cdot K } e^{-i\phi n\cdot J}\nonumber\\
=&e^{bH} e^{a\cdot P} e^{a\cdot P }e^{b'H}e^{-i\theta n\cdot J} e^{n\cdot J} e^{i\theta n\cdot J}e^{-i\theta n\cdot J}e^{v'\cdot K } e^{i\theta n\cdot J}e^{-i\theta n\cdot J}e^{-i\phi n\cdot J} \nonumber\\
=&e^{bH} e^{a\cdot P} e^{a\cdot P }e^{b'H}e^{Rn\cdot J} e^{Rv'\cdot K }RR' \nonumber\\
=&e^{bH}e^{b'H}e^{-b'H} e^{a\cdot P} e^{b'H}e^{-b'H}e^{a\cdot P }e^{b'H}e^{Rn\cdot J} e^{Rv'\cdot K }RR' \nonumber\\
=&e^{(b+b')H}(e^{-b'H} e^{a\cdot P+a\cdot P}e^{b'H})e^{Rn\cdot J} e^{Rv'\cdot K }RR' 
\end{align}\
To caculate things with H:
\begin{align} \label{eq:kine2ex1}
&e^{-b'H} e^{a\cdot P+a\cdot P}e^{b'H}\nonumber\\
=&e^{-b'H} (\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n!}(a\cdot P+a\cdot P)^n})e^{b'H}\nonumber\\
=&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{e^{-b'H} (\frac{1}{n!}(a\cdot P+a\cdot P)^n) e^{b'H}}\nonumber\\
=&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(e^{-b'H} \frac{1}{n!}(a\cdot P+a\cdot P) e^{b'H})^n}\nonumber\\
=&\exp[e^{-b'H}(a\cdot P+a\cdot P) e^{b'H}]\nonumber\\
=&\exp[a\cdot \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}{( -b') ^m\frac{1}{m!}\underbrace{[H,[H,\ldots [H,}_{m's}P]..]}+v\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}{( -b' ) ^m\underbrace{[H,[H,\ldots [H,}_{m's}K]..]}e^{b'H})] \nonumber\\
\end{align}\
To shorten, use $\diamond_{AB}$ for “change between A and B”,[m]means round m to a larger integer：
\begin{align} \label{eq:kine2ex2}
\exp\Bigg[a&\cdot \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}{( -b') ^m\frac{1}{m!}\underbrace{[H,[H,\ldots [H,}_{m's}P]..]}+v\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}{( -b' ) ^m\frac{1}{m!}\underbrace{[H,[H,\ldots [H,}_{m's}K]..]}\Bigg] \nonumber\\
= \exp\Bigg[a& \cdot \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (-b')^m \frac{1}{m!} (\diamond_{PK})^m \cdot \frac{P}{(\pm \tau^2)^{[\frac{m}{2}]}} 
+ v \cdot \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (-b')^m \frac{1}{m!} (\diamond_{PK})^m \cdot \frac{K}{(\pm \tau^2)^{[\frac{m}{2}]}} \Bigg]\nonumber\\ 
=\exp\Bigg[a&\cdot \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}{(( -b') ^{2m} P \frac{(\pm)^{m}}{(2m)!\tau ^{2m}}+( -b') ^{2m+1} K \frac{(\pm)^{m+1}}{(2m+1)!\tau ^{2m+2}})}\nonumber\\
+&v\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}{(( -b') ^{2m} K \frac{(\pm)^{m}}{(2m)!\tau ^{2m}}+( -b') ^{2m+1} P \frac{(\pm)^{m}}{(2m+1)!\tau ^{2m}})}\Bigg]\nonumber\\
=\exp\Bigg[a&\cdot \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}{(( -b') ^{2m} P \frac{(\pm)^{m}}{(2m)!\tau ^{2m}}+\frac{1}{\tau}( -b') ^{2m+1} K \frac{(\pm)^{m+1}}{(2m+1)!\tau ^{2m+1}})}\nonumber\\
+&v\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}{(( -b') ^{2m} K \frac{(\pm)^{m}}{(2m)!\tau ^{2m}}+\tau( -b') ^{2m+1} P \frac{(\pm)^{m}}{(2m+1)!\tau ^{2m+1}})}\Bigg]\nonumber\\
=&\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
\exp\Big[a\cdot P\mathrm{cosh}(\frac{-b'}{\tau})+\tau v\cdot P\mathrm{sinh}(\frac{-b'}{\tau})+a\cdot P\mathrm{cosh}(\frac{-b'}{\tau})+\frac{1}{\tau}a\cdot K\mathrm{sinh}(\frac{-b'}{\tau})\Big]&\\
&(N_+)\\
\exp\Big[a\cdot P\mathrm{cos}(\frac{-b'}{\tau})+\tau v\cdot P\mathrm{sin}(\frac{-b'}{\tau})+a\cdot P\mathrm{cos}(\frac{-b'}{\tau})+\frac{1}{\tau}a\cdot K\mathrm{sin}(\frac{-b'}{\tau})\Big]&\\
&(N_-)\\
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}\
The $\sinh(\frac{-b'}{\tau})/ \sin(\frac{-b'}{\tau})$ in  the final result is the wrong part, as the original is $\sinh(\frac{b'}{\tau})/ \sin(\frac{b'}{\tau})$ . Which is correct? with or without minus?
The original result is the pic, while it doesnt provide any detail process.
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/oFz9HdA4.png

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
